# Filter a CQWP on a Lookup Column

Tags: lookup-column, content-query-web-part, filter, publishing-page

I'm creating a custom page layout that contains a CQWP that I'd like to display documents related to the page. The document library has a lookup column that relates to the page title in the Pages library. In the CQWP I've got a filter value of `[PageFieldValue: Title]`.

I can't get the CQWP to display any documents. If I instead filter on a `"Single Line of Text"` field where I manually type the Page Title, it works fine, so I know it's not an issue with the filter value.

I assume the issue is that the lookup field is actually returning something like `"1#;Page Title"`, but I don't know how to account for that in my filter.

Comment: I appreciate it would mean adding another step but how about adding a topic column to your page library and using that to filter on instead?  You could either create a separate lookup list and have both the page library and the document library lookup from this or use a term set. Another possibility is to add the Title as a URL parameter and filter with that instead?